# Expected Value of product of random variables multiplied by a common random variable

Tags: variance, expected-value, covariance

So apologies if this has been asked before, but I've been searching around for an answer to this for a few days and not found one.
My question is what would be the result of this:
\begin{equation}
E[A(t)^2 B(t)C(t)],
\end{equation}
where A(t),B(t) and C(t) are random unrelated variables with expectations of $A_E,B_E,C_E$ and variances given by $A_V,B_V,C_V$.

If it helps, I need to know this as I am attempting to calculate:
\begin{equation}
Cov(A(t)B(t),A(t)C(t)),
\end{equation}
and I have already determined that:
\begin{equation}
E[A(t)B(t)]E[A(t)C(t)] = A_E^2 B_E C_E.
\end{equation}

Edit: After reading the responses, it is now clear that I should clarify the variables are mutually independant.

Comment: You don't have enough information for an answer: you need to know something equivalent to $E[A(t)^2].$

Comment: Could that not be determined from $E[A(t)] = A_E$? What other information will I need?

Comment: Apologies if my questions seem basic, I am only just learning statistics as I am a Physicist by trade and only recently have needed an understanding of this for my project.

Comment: The expectation is a center of mass.  The expectation of the square is a moment of inertia: you cannot infer anything about the latter from the former.

Comment: @whuber I wouldn't go as far as "you cannot infer _anything_ about the latter from the former."  After all, we do know that $E[X^2] \geq (E[X])^2$ and so the square of the former is a lower bound on the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what $t$ is doing in the OP's notation and so will ignore it here.

The key is what is the meaning of "unrelated" in "random unrelated variables".

- If "unrelated" merely means *different,* then, as whuber points out in a comment on the OP's question, there is not enough information to answer the question.
- If "unrelated" means *mutually independent* in the probabilistic or stochastic sense of the word, then
  $$E[A^2BC] = E[A^2]E[B]E[C] = (A_V+A_E^2)B_EC_E.$$
  Thus, $\operatorname{cov}(AB,AC)$ which is what the OP says he really wants to determine, is given by \begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(AB,AC)&= E[A^2BC]-E[AB]E[AC]\\
  &= (A_V+A_E^2)B_EC_E - A_E^2B_EC_E\\
  &= A_VB_EC_E
  \end{align}
- If "unrelated" means **pairwise** *independent* in the probabilistic or stochastic sense of the word, then it is *not necessarily* the case that 
  $E[A^2BC] = E[A^2]E[B]E[C]$ and so we cannot claim that $E[A^2BC] = (A_V+A_E^2)B_EC_E$ holds in all cases. It is still true that  $E[AB] = A_EB_E$ and $E[AC] = A_EC_E$, but we are stuck at
  $$\operatorname{cov}(AB,AC) = E[A^2BC]-A_E^2B_EC_E$$ 
  and cannot proceed further as in the mutually independent case discussed above. Once again, there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, that is a really helpful response, looking into the definitions I believe my system is mutually independent so we have our answer. Also, the t is a relic from some earlier calculations, if you're curious. I have to be aware of the time variance at different spatial positions so I usually represent the variables as V(x,t).